# Make intrinsicContentSize adapt to external constraints

Tags: swift, nsview, appkit

### The Context

I often have situations where I want multiple `NSTextView`s in a single `NSStackView`. Naturally, Auto Layout is not pleased with this since this makes height ambiguous (assuming the stack view is not set to fill equally). Even after adding constraints to resolve these issues, macOS Interface Builder appears to have a bug where it refuses to actually update frames when asked.

For this reason and others, I'm attempting to create a `TextBox` class (subclassing `NSView`) to encapsulate an `NSTextView` (and associated scroll view) and include an intrinsic content size to avoid layout issues. The intrinsic content size would be calculated based on a user-specified min and max number of lines (to display without requiring scroll). In other words, up to a certain max number of lines, `TextBox` will resize itself so that scrolling is unnecessary.

### The Problem

**This would seem to require an `intrinsicContentSize` that is dependant on frame width.**

But, `intrinsicContentSize` documentation [states](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsview/1526996-intrinsiccontentsize):

> The intrinsic size you supply must be independent of the content frame, because there’s no way to dynamically communicate a changed width to the layout system based on a changed height.

However, Auto Layout Guide [states](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/AnatomyofaConstraint.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH9-SW21):

> A text view’s intrinsic content size varies depending on the content, on whether or not it has scrolling enabled, and on the other constraints applied to the view. For example, with scrolling enabled, the view does not have an intrinsic content size. With scrolling disabled, by default the view’s intrinsic content size is calculated based on the size of the text without any line wrapping. For example, if there are no returns in the text, it calculates the height and width needed to layout the content as a single line of text. If you add constraints to specify the view’s width, the intrinsic content size defines the height required to display the text given its width.

Given that when scrolling is disabled in a text view:

> If you add constraints to specify the view’s width, the intrinsic content size defines the height required to display the text given its width.

Then it seems there is a way to do what I want by perhaps looking at existing constraints.

### The Question

How can I define an intrinsic content size that calculates height based on otherwise specified width, as described in the last quoted sentence above?

The solution should produce the effect described in "The Context" and not produce errors or warnings when used inside a Stack View.